# Plot function with large binomial coefficients

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I would like to plot a function which involves binomial coefficients. The code I have is

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from __future__ import division
from scipy.special import binom
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

max = 500
ycoords = [sum([binom(n,w)*sum([binom(w,k)*(binom(w,k)/2**w)**(4*n/math.log(n)) for k in xrange(w+1)]) for w in xrange(1,n+1)]) for n in xrange(2,max)]

xcoords = range(2,max)

plt.plot(xcoords, ycoords)
plt.show()
```

Unfortunately this never terminates. If you reduce max to 40 say it works fine.  Is there some way to plot this function?

I am also worried that scipy.special.binom might not be giving accurate answers as it works in floating point it seems.

Comment: Your code seems to work fine, I ran it as is and although it did take a significant amount of time, that's to be expected when you are working with 500 terms.  Also, the plot worked fine.  I'm unclear what the problem is.

Comment: @TroyRockwood I think that binom(n,w) is only accurate to 53 bits so the picture you get won't be right will it?

Comment: That's a different question than "it never terminates" or "can you plot it", obviously the result will be limited by the accuracy of the variable precision that is used.  Maybe a little indication about what the application of the question would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get significant speedup by using numpy to compute the inner loop. First change `max` to `N` (since `max` is a builtin) and break up your function into smaller, more manageable chunks:

```
N = 500
X = np.arange(2,N)

def k_loop(w,n):
    K = np.arange(0, w+1)
    return (binom(w,K)*(binom(w,K)/2**w)**(float(n)/np.log(n))).sum()

def w_loop(n):
    v = [binom(n,w)*k_loop(w,n) for w in range(1,n+1)]
    return sum(v)

Y = [w_loop(n) for n in X]
```

Using `N=300` as a test it takes `3.932s` with the numpy code, but `81.645s` using your old code. I didn't even time the `N=500` case since your old code took so long!

It's worth pointing out that your function is basically exponential growth and can be approximated as such. You can see this in a `semilogx` plot:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I also edited the formula slightly to make it more sensible (see the new factor of 4).